# Is it possible to query a linked server of a remote server? / Acces FoxPro data from SQL Server x64

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, foxpro, visual-foxpro

Scenary:

- SQL Server 2005 x64 (default instance)
- Data on Fox Pro .dbf. Only 32 bit driver available (no x64 driver)

I need to access the FoxPro data from the default SQL Server instance. I used to do it with linked servers created on SQL Server, but this is no longer possible on the x64 instance (driver compatibility).

So, I installed a new SQL Server instance of 32 bits (SS32 for short) and created the linked servers on this new instance to acces the .dbf data using the existing driver.

In this server I can query the .dfb data like this:

- `select * from LinkedServerName...DbfTableName` and it works fine

But I still need to access it from the default instance.

So, this is what I have

- SQL Server x64 default instance
- SQL Server 32 (SS32) instance with linked servers to acces the foxpro data

Is there any way to query the linked servers in SS32 from the default instance? Do you know of any possible alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the x64 instance you can use `OPENQUERY` to run a query on a linked server:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OPENQUERY(x86LinkedServer, 'select *
                                     from LinkedServerName...DbfTableName')
```

There is also [this blog post](http://information-management-enabled.blogspot.com.au/2005/11/access-database-from-sql-200564.html) regarding a workaround for what is (basically) your problem: querying a 32-bit datasource from a 64-bit instance.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're right, but you swapped the params. This works like a charm: select * from openquery([(local)\ss32],'select * from LinkedServername...DbfTableName'). Please, corerct your answer so I can say it's correct.